# Lists to dictionary with specific values

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have lists

```
list_keys = ['a', 'b', 'c']
list_a = ['a', 'a1', 'a2']
list_c = ['c', 'c1', 'c2']
```

I need py solution that will create a dict using `list_keys` elements as keys and `list_a`, `list_c` as values. Script should look at `list_keys` and match values according to first element of `list_a`, `list_c`. Also, it should leave elements from `list_keys` with no matching first values from other lists. See the desired output here:

```
{'a' : ['a', 'a1', 'a2'],
 'b' : [],
 'c' : ['c', 'c1', 'c2']}
```

My code snippet is not working correct and I would like to avoid combining lists (`cmb`) if possible

```
list_keys = ['a', 'b', 'c']
list_a = ['a', 'a1', 'a2']
list_c = ['c', 'c1', 'c2']
cmb = list_a, list_c

d = {}
for k,v in zip(list_keys, cmb):
    d[k] = v
print(d)
```

Incorrect output:

```
{'a': ['a', 'a1', 'a2'],
 'b': ['c', 'c1', 'c2']}
```

Comment: You need to provide something for `b`: `cmb = list_a, [], list_c`

Comment: Beside the point, but `list` is a bad variable name since it [shadows](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable_shadowing) the [builtin `list` type](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#list). In example code it's not a big problem, just confusing, but it'd be better to use a more descriptive name like `keys`. Cf. [Why does "example = list(...)" result in "TypeError: 'list' object is not callable"?](/q/31087111/4518341).

Comment: Why do you have `list_a, list_c` in the first place? I would understand if they were together, like `values = [['a', 'a1', 'a2'], ['c', 'c1', 'c2']]`, but them being separate lists is strange, and it's also strange that they're named according to their contents. If that's just how you've written the example, fair enough, but you might want to consider whether this is an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/343832) or at least if the example could be clarified by being a little more grounded in reality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hmmm... The original solution I made includes combining lists (makes it more convenient for adding more lists in the future, and also enables using a loop to iterate the lists). But here I'll give 2 snippets:

**With combining lists**

```py
list = ['a', 'b', 'c']
list_a = ['a', 'a1', 'a2']
list_c = ['c', 'c1', 'c2']

lists = [list_a, list_c]  # Lists to check
dic = {}
for elem in list:
    matchedList = []
    for L in lists:
        if elem == L[0]:
            matchedList = L
    dic[elem] = matchedList
print(dic)
```

**Without combining lists**

```py
list = ['a', 'b', 'c']
list_a = ['a', 'a1', 'a2']
list_c = ['c', 'c1', 'c2']

dic = {}
for elem in list:
    matchedList = []
    if elem == list_a[0]:
        matchedList = list_a
    if elem == list_c[0]:
        matchedList = list_c
    # This is what I meant, without combining lists we pretty much need to copy the same piece of code
    dic[elem] = matchedList
print(dic)
```

Also, just a tip, notice how the variable name `list` is colored? That's because `list` is the name of an *inbuilt function* – it's recommended *not* to use those as variable names. (In this case, the function `list()` doesn't work because we used that as a variable name!)

Comment: Beside the point, but [`l` is a bad variable name since it looks like `1` and `I`](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#names-to-avoid); you could use `L` instead. It'd be even better to use a more descriptive name, but the question doesn't have any context so it's hard to say. I made up new names for [my answer](/a/76122579/4518341).

Comment: BTW, check out [PEP 8](https://peps.python.org/pep-0008/), the official Python style guide. I just edited the answer to make it more readable.

Comment: @wjandrea oh cool, thanks for those! The original one was quite squished because I sometimes code golf haha

Answer (score 2):

This example seems strange to me since `list_a, list_c` are named according to their contents, so I'm going to change the structure to reflect how I'm understanding the actual problem (and avoid [shadowing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable_shadowing) `list` too):

```
keys = ['a', 'b', 'c']
values = [
    ['a', 'a1', 'a2'],
    ['c', 'c1', 'c2']]
```

So now it's clear that we can just grab each first element from `values` and use it to access an existing dict that we created with the keys from `keys`.

```
d = {k: [] for k in keys}
for v in values:
    k = v[0]
    d[k] = v
```

Result:

```
{'a': ['a', 'a1', 'a2'],
 'b': [],
 'c': ['c', 'c1', 'c2']}
```

Comment: You could also make use of a `defaultdict` to handle the missing values.

Comment: @BRemmelzwaal I considered that, but I didn't see how it would be any cleaner, and I'd just have to convert it back to `dict` anyway, assuming OP needs a `dict` proper. But if you have something in mind, I wouldn't mind seeing it :)

Comment: I just assumed that since this is a mock example, there could be many non-existent keys within the lists, so using a defaultdict would maybe be more space efficient. It was a _could_ though, your solution perfectly answers the question as posed :)

Answer (score 1):

Combination of dictionary and list comprehension:

```
list_keys = ['a', 'b', 'c']
list_a = ['a', 'a1', 'a2']
list_c = ['c', 'c1', 'c2']

d = {letter: [element for element in (list_a+list_c) if element[0] == letter] for letter in list_keys}
```